# richtextbox with greek characters display as?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to create a custom MessageBox form.
I want to display in a richtextbox greek characters but i get ????.
The code to call the custom form:

```
 string msg = "Greek: αβγδ NotGreek:abcd";
                    using (MsgForm frm = new MsgForm("Caption", msg))
                    {
                        frm.ShowDialog();
                    }
```

The code of the form with the richtextbox

```
public MsgForm(string caption, string text)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ " + _text + "}";
        }
```

d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display (or write to file) Greek characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889148/how-to-display-or-write-to-file-greek-characters)

Comment: Here is another question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228606/greek-text-not-displayed-correctly

Comment: Use the RichTextbox.Text property instead, it does all the hard work of properly generating the RTF for you.  Gets you over the first basic hump, you'll no doubt discover the Font and SelectionColor properties next to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I wrote the greek chars in wordpad, saved the file in rtf format and open it with notepad. Doing so i managed to write a replace function for the Greek chars:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = _caption;
            Replace();
            richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1253 " + _text + "}";
        }

 private void Replace()
        {
            _text = _text.Replace("α", "\\'e1");
            _text = _text.Replace("β", "\\'e2");
            _text = _text.Replace("γ", "\\'e3");
            _text = _text.Replace("δ", "\\'e4");
            _text = _text.Replace("ε", "\\'e5");
            _text = _text.Replace("ζ", "\\'e6");
            _text = _text.Replace("η", "\\'e7");
            _text = _text.Replace("θ", "\\'e8");
            _text = _text.Replace("ι", "\\'e9");
            _text = _text.Replace("κ", "\\'ea");
            _text = _text.Replace("λ", "\\'eb");
            _text = _text.Replace("μ", "\\'ec");
            _text = _text.Replace("ν", "\\'ed");
            _text = _text.Replace("ξ", "\\'ee");
            _text = _text.Replace("ο", "\\'ef");
            _text = _text.Replace("π", "\\'f0");
            _text = _text.Replace("ρ", "\\'f1");
            _text = _text.Replace("ς", "\\'f2");
            _text = _text.Replace("σ", "\\'f3");
            _text = _text.Replace("τ", "\\'f4");
            _text = _text.Replace("υ", "\\'f5");
            _text = _text.Replace("φ", "\\'f6");
            _text = _text.Replace("χ", "\\'f7");
            _text = _text.Replace("ψ", "\\'f8");
            _text = _text.Replace("ω", "\\'f9");

            _text = _text.Replace("Α", "\\'c1");
            _text = _text.Replace("Β", "\\'c2");
            _text = _text.Replace("Γ", "\\'c3");
            _text = _text.Replace("Δ", "\\'c4");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ε", "\\'c5");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ζ", "\\'c6");
            _text = _text.Replace("Η", "\\'c7");
            _text = _text.Replace("Θ", "\\'c8");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ι", "\\'c9");
            _text = _text.Replace("Κ", "\\'ca");
            _text = _text.Replace("Λ", "\\'cb");
            _text = _text.Replace("Μ", "\\'cc");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ν", "\\'cd");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ξ", "\\'ce");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ο", "\\'cf");
            _text = _text.Replace("Π", "\\'d0");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ρ", "\\'d1");
            _text = _text.Replace("Σ", "\\'d3");
            _text = _text.Replace("Τ", "\\'d4");
            _text = _text.Replace("Υ", "\\'d5");
            _text = _text.Replace("Φ", "\\'d6");
            _text = _text.Replace("Χ", "\\'d7");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ψ", "\\'d8");
            _text = _text.Replace("Ω", "\\'d9");

            _text = _text.Replace("ά", "\\'dc");
            _text = _text.Replace("έ", "\\'dd");
            _text = _text.Replace("ή", "\\'de");
            _text = _text.Replace("ί", "\\'df");
            _text = _text.Replace("ό", "\\'fc");
            _text = _text.Replace("ύ", "\\'fd");
            _text = _text.Replace("ώ", "\\'fe");

            _text = _text.Replace("ϋ", "\\'fb");
            _text = _text.Replace("ϊ", "\\'fa");
            _text = _text.Replace("ΰ", "\\'e0");
            _text = _text.Replace("ΐ", "\\'c0");
        }
```

Comment: Kinda not very orthodox but does the job and I used it too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `\rtf1\ansi\` and make sure that your editor saves the files in UTF-8 encoding.